# Problem involving series divisibility

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, divisibility

I'm in doubt about this problem!
How do I show that $3(1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2)$ is divisible by $(1+2+...+n)$?

I thought about using that $ (1 + 2 + .. + n) =\frac{n (n+1)}{2}$ and that $(1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2)=\frac{n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, but it didn't work out very well!
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\times(2n+1)=3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet it's pretty obvious:
$$3(1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}2=(1+2+\dots+n)(2n+1).$$

Comment: Wow !!!
I had used that a | b ==> ax = b and came up with something I didn't know how to solve.

You are right, the way you put it is very obvious!

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, Bernard, can you explain me better, please, the steps of the eguagliance? +1

Comment: Hi, Sebastiano! Nothing very clever: I multiplied the formula for the sum of squared by 3 and factored out the sum of the $n$ first  positive integers. As the O.P. knew these formulæ, it was just a matter of rewriting.